# Is there any native client for Mondrian?

Tags: olap, business-intelligence, pentaho, mondrian

Now I'm start to study Pentaho and still working on Mondrian
right now I confusing that does it have a native client for Mondrian?

How do I start? Is there any document, tool or source that I should to understand

Thanks for every answer.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at Saiku - this gives you a powerful open source olap client.

Also; If you download PDI/kettle you can actually use analyzer indirectly via the vizualisation tab. (Agile BI it's called)

If you just want to fire MDX at mondrian and see the result then you can do this in schema workbench.

Comment: hi codek , can you please share your thoughts on below thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878574/parametrized-transformation-from-pentaho-di-server-console

Answer (score 1):

In Pentaho Enterprise Edition, the Mondrian client is Analyzer (select "New Analysis" from the User Console welcome screen).

Comment: Analyzer is EE only, and as this user is studying I doubt they have an EE license! :)  But of course, the old Jpivot view should still be there for now.

Comment: @Codek:  Good point.  Sounded to me like they might be evaluating, though.  Downloading and installing an evaluation copy of Enterprise is absolutely the fastest way to preview what is possible.

Comment: @Codek: right now I develop Mondrian on community edition. If I need to develop native client on my own. What should I do and do I start.

Comment: @Supajak Thamwongsa:  I think Codek's suggestion of Saiku is a good one.  I believe it can be embedded, and is open source, so you can examine how it works for yourself, if you truly need to create another client.  Easiest route might be embedding Saiku (or Pentaho, which also has integration options) in your app.

Comment: what do you mean by native by the way? what language are we talking here. There are already olap4php and olap4j libraries, not entirely sure what you're trying to do!  Whatever you do, dont re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @Codek I'm trying to develop native application on Windows 8 tablet by focusing on report feature. It will look like saiku can do but I will do on tablet. What library that I should looking into.

Comment: I would talk to the saiku guys. they are working on tablet support via some of the tablet supported jquery libraries I think. They would know  best!

Comment: @Codek Thanks for your help. It is possible to have something to contact to you directly like your e-mail so it will not make the comment too long here and we will discuss about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a try a pure javascript pivot table component at [webpivottable](http://webpivottable.com) . It connect to XMLA service directly and support Mondrian, Microsoft SSAS, iccube.