# Parametrized transformation from Pentaho DI server console

Tags: transformation, pentaho, etl

I can execute a independent scheduled transformation from pentaho DI server console . `But, issue on running a parametrized scheduled transformation from pentaho DI server console .How can i pass parameter value at run time .`

In pentaho BI server , **to execute parametrized report we used to pass variable value in URL** . tried same in pentho DI server as below but didnt worked

> http://********/pentaho-di/kettle/transStatus?name=UI_parameter&Values=Testvalue

Comment: Tried below command to start transformation , but still parameter is not passed [link]

http://localhost:9080/pentaho-di/kettle/startTrans?name=UI_parameter&Values=Testvalue

Comment: any suggestion would be a gr8 help